# Angular2 beta and gulp-tsc - Cannot find module 'angular2/core'

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular, typescript1.8, gulp-typescript

I am trying to automate the typescript compilation with the new angular 2.0 beta.

The **project structure** is:

```
myapp
|--node_modules
     |---angular2
            |--core.d.ts
            |--...
|--lib
    |--resources
         |--app
             |--app.component.ts
|--typings
     |--..
.
|--package.json
|--gulpfile.js
```

**app.component.ts** excerpt:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {TechnologiesService} from './services';
```

When I run the typescript command (tsc) directly from the shell everything goes well and the javascript files are generated. However when I run my gulp compile task there are some errors because it doesn't find angular2/core and angular2/platform/browser modules. Why?

```
[16:35:55] Using gulpfile C:\dev\myapp\gulpfile.js
[16:35:55] Starting 'compile-ts'...
[16:35:55] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.8.2
[16:35:56] [tsc] > lib/resources/app/app.component.ts(1,46): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
[16:35:56] [tsc] > lib/resources/app/app.component.ts(44,14): error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
[16:35:56] [tsc] > lib/resources/app/main.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'.
[16:35:56] Failed to compile TypeScript: Error: tsc command has exited with code:2

events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error: Failed to compile: tsc command has exited with code:2
```

gulpfile **typescript compilation task**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');
gulp.task('compile-ts', function(){
  return gulp.src(['./lib/resources/app/**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(typescript({"target": "es5", "module": "system", "moduleResolution": "node", "sourceMap": true,
                      "experimentalDecorators": true, "emitDecoraasdftorMetadata": true, "removeComments": false,
                      "noImplicitAny": false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/app/'));
});
```

Comment: Do you have typings installed and included? Eg. `/// <reference path="../typings/main.d.ts" />`

Comment: When I ran npm install the typings folder was created (myapp/typings). Just tried adding `/// <reference path="../../../typings/main.d.ts" />` but still complains about angular2/core. Also put `/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts" />`and nothing changes.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a working directory issue. Have you tried specifying rootDir?

Comment: @Harangue yes, it seems related to the working dir. I tried setting `"sourceRoot: "./"` as parameter in `.pipe(typescript({})` but same result...Other test with `"sourceRoot: "../../../"`, etc...

Comment: Do you have a local typescript installation? You could try using the global one.

Comment: I had installed typescript globally with npm install -g typescript@1.8.2. It was also included in node_modules so I deleted that dir. Anyway, it still fails :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using gulp-typescript instead of gulp-tsc and the following gulpfile.js is working perfectly with tsconfig.json file specified.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var path = require('path');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('build:client', function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('client/tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = gulp.src([
        'client/**/*.ts',
        '!client/typings/main/**/*.ts',
        '!client/typings/main.d.ts'
    ])        
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('server'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['build:client']);
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir":"./"    
  },
  "exclude": [    
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

To install Typings

```
npm install typings --save-dev
```

Initialize the typings.json

```
typings init
```

To Install Typings for "es6-collections" and "es6-promise"

```
typings install es6-collections --ambient --save
typings install es6-promise --ambient --save
```

Comment: I just tested it and got 76 semantic errors: `dopangular/node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(77,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.`, `/dopangular/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(23,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.`, etc. On the other hand, although the sourcemap files are missing, the .js files are correctly generated and the application runs ok. Any idea why I got those errors? Why aren't there any sourcemap files?

Comment: The compilation errors are shown because it could not find the typings for the mentioned entities. Try installing the ambient typings for "es6-collections" and "es6-promise".  The sourcemap is appended into the js files generated.

Comment: I'm completely new to ts... how do I install the ambient typings? Thanks for helping me out ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same errors. Could you have a quick look at the project? https://github.com/codependent/dopangular/tree/beta. Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you try providing the typings in the lib/resources/app folder? Can you also try changing the rootDir property in tsconfig to the app folder? Either doing one or both will work..

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html This will help you understand typescript type resolution strategies.

Comment: Almost there... now it finds them but warns about duplicated identifiers: `lib\resources\app\typings\browser\ambient\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(24,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
lib\resources\app - lib\resources\app\typings\browser\ambient\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(25,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'. `etc. Since everything works I've accepted your answer. I wonder why it complains about the duplicates though.

Comment: While installing a typing, it provides you with with 2 versions, one for the browser and one for node. In our case we need to exclude the type definitions meant for node in gulp.src.. Like the one in my answer..

Comment: Everything cleared up! Thank you for taking the time to explain.